# Windows Homegroup (Wi-Fi) sharing but without Internet connection?

Tags: windows, windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, homegroup

How can Homegroup sharing work in Windows 8 and 8.1?

At the moment, I have setup Homegroup sharing. And currently, it only works when the computers are connected to the internet.

I would like to be able to share files through Homegroup sharing wirelessly but without an internet connection. Is this possible? Both PC's have built-in wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless:

That is possible by creating a Ad hoc network on a computer, then others connect to that network. After they connected, you can share files as a normal WORKGROUP network. You can read details how to create Ad hoc network [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/vi-vn/windows-vista/ad-hoc-networking-how-the-network-with-the-funny-name-can-make-your-life-easier) (with illustration pictures).

Wirelessly way allows you can share files among more than 2 PCs. If you have only 2 PCs and a Ethernet cable, refer another way below, otherwise please ignore it.

Wired (optional):

If you has a Ethernet cable, you can use it to connect 2 PCs directly, then manually set up their IP address with the same netmask and default gateway. Example:

PC A:

```
IP: 192.168.1.100
netmask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

PC B:

```
IP: 192.168.1.200
netmask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Then you can share files between 2 computer as normal LAN network.